# Passing an object of MainActivity through View.OnClickListener()

Tags: java, android, parameter-passing, onclicklistener

Below is an example of My app's MainActivity.java:

```
/*imports and other stuffs*/

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

Button myButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.first_button);
   // myButton.setOnClickListener(this); by using it, app works as desired.


    myButton.setOnClickListener(new MainActivity()); //What's wrong with this piece of codes?

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v.getId()==R.id.first_button){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Made it", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

As setOnClickListener() method requires an object of a class that implements View.setOnClickListener, it can be handled with a custom class implements View.setOnClickListener, but my question, as a beginner, is what's going on actually, while passing an object of MainActivity?

**Edit:**

But if I pass an object of another class and pass that one, the code works perfectly, doesn't it? and what about those codes:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button myButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.first_button);


    myButton.setOnClickListener(new MyClass());


}

class MyClass implements View.OnClickListener{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("buttontest","Working Perfectly");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: if you want your current activity to handle clicks you just pass `this`, passing new instance of activity is not gonna do you good, you should let OS create activities for you, not spawn them yourself

Comment: @OlegBogdanov that is what I am doing but actually can't figure it out what's causing problem here.

Comment: but you forgot to tell what is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new MainActivity());
```

With that piece of code you are setting on OnClickListener for your **myButton**. However, you are not creating the correct listener object. You are creating a new MainActivity object that is not the correct type.

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

This is correct, because the class implements **View.OnClickListener** and has the implementation with the *void onClick(View v)* method in the class.

You can also do this if you like too:

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // add code here
            }
        });
```

This will create an new OnClickListener object with the onClick method implemented as well. This is passing an anonymous class to the setOnClickListener.

Comment: Would you please clarify me what's the difference between passing an object of MainActivity class (as it implements View.SetOnClickListener) and passing this?

Comment: `this` refers to the current object. In your example, it refers to the `MainActivity`. This works because your `MainActivity` implements the `View.OnClickListener` interface.

Comment: @Orbit this refers to the current object of MainActivity and MainActivity implemented View.OnClickListener, still passing an object of this class actually causing problems in my app, however an object of any class, except MainActivity , works perfectly, can anybody let me know what's wrong here?

Comment: @Sumon Your question does not make sense. Please post another question with errors and code examples and explain your issue plainly.

Comment: @Sumon you are passing the class object that implements the interface. The method knows about the interface so it sees the View.OnClickListener and not MainActivity. If your activity implements the interface you can pass that to the setOnClickListener method.

Comment: @srayhunter yes I can pass MainActivity by using this, however why it doesn't work if I pass an object of MainActivity? For example: myButton.setOnClickListener(new MainActivity());  this one doesn't wok, means causes my app to crush.

Comment: @Sumon Check this out - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html that will help explain interfaces.